# Where can I find oracle.security.jps.service.credstore.Credential jar

Tags: java

Where can I find jar for following packages `oracle.security.jps.service.credstore.Credential`?

I am following this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/javase-cloud/csjsu/using-command-line-interface-manage-oracle-java-cloud-service-saas-extension.html#GUID-2F1A4B6C-14D0-4FDC-A91B-09BE213D3A95), but cannot find the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

This class find in jps-api.jar file which is available in Oracle maven repository which is proprietary. 
Also you can check for this jar file in your application server libraries folder.

Comment: i can't find it as maven dependency

Comment: @Shaaban, it is proprietary which is found in Oracle maven repository. You can't find it on any public maven repository.

Comment: @Shaaban, adding to my comment, You have to download this jar file from oracle maven repository and should include it as a system level dependency in your local repository.